# ERROR TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON Angular 8

Tags: serialization, angular8, stringify

I'm using Angular 8 and i need to stringify a structured object and later on parse it,

I've tried to stringify the object by using a few libraries that i've seen in a related posts, but none of them worked like i expected ..

[serialijse](https://github.com/erossignon/serialijse) and [flatted](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flatted)
Both of them didn't gave me the result i was looking for - which is obviously - a "dummy" object without circular reference ... i wonder what is the best way there is .